# Windows Login Password and Other Variables Being Used as Seed with CryptProtectData function?

Tags: encryption, windows, database

Detailed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380261(v=vs.85).aspx), it mentions:

> "Typically, only a user with the same logon credential as the user who
>   encrypted the data can decrypt the data. In addition, the encryption
>   and decryption usually must be done on the same computer."

Is there any documentation anywhere as to what additional seeds it takes into consideration when encrypting/decrypting the data? The intention is to decrypt it on another workstation on my network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That API is a black box. The design goal was to create an API for developer where they wouldn't have to do any of the hard work of encrypting data so you do not have any more control on the key generation process than the additional (optional) entropy and specify whether the key will be linked to the user account (in which case you can decrypt the data on any other machine where the user can be logged on) or the local machine (in which case any local user will have access to the data)

Any other option would make it impossible to automate the key management process.

That said, you can easily decrypt the same data on a different machine as long as you didn't use CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE in the flags and you're using the same user account.

Comment: So that being said, nothing is known about the key generation process assuming the CRYPTPROTECT_LOCAL_MACHINE flag is used?

Comment: Nothing documented at least.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the input!